# Create and estimate a FAVAR

Tags: r, vector-autoregression

I try to estimate a factor augmented VAR model. I estimated 4 factors by PCA and added them to my data set.

`factor augmented data set = [f1' f2' f3' f4' variables']`

Then I estimated this FAVAR in `R` by `VAR(factor augmented data set)` (`vars package`). I couldn't find an answer somewhere, if that's the right way doing it. Is it possible to simply add the factors to my data set and estimate it as VAR model as usual, or do I have to consider something special? Thank you for your help.

Comment: Yes that is the two-step method to estimate the FAVAR although there is also a single-step Bayesian method. Note that you'll have to correct the s.e.'s! See the paper by Bernanke, Boivin and Eliasz (2005). They discuss the two-step approach on p. 398-399. Its available here: http://faculty.wcas.northwestern.edu/~lchrist/finc520/QJE.pdf

Comment: Most papers using the FAVAR methodology discuss which method they use and often they also discuss the estimation process. So a look at papers using the FAVAR. Another paper to look at is Stock and Watson.(2005). IMPLICATIONS OF DYNAMIC FACTOR MODELS
FOR VAR ANALYSIS: http://crei.cat/conferences/Macroeconomics_and_Reality,_25_years_later/activities/sc_conferences/22/Papers/stock.pdf

Comment: Thank you @Plissken , I will read it right now. I already knew Stock and Watson, but I wasn't sure if I really just can add my factors to the data set or if I have missed something. It seemed just too simple. But it appears, that's exactly the way it works.